# How to remove `.html` extension and `yyyy/dd/mm` from URL in excel?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have thousands of URLs to re-write. Therefore I tried to remove the `.html` extension and `date(yyyy/mm/dd)` from the URL. I can remove the extension. But I was unable to remove the date from the string.

Can anybody help me out?

I want remove date either this way `2020/11/05/` or this way `/2020/11/05`

How it looks: `https://www.example.com/2020/11/05/my-post-slug-for-this-post-2022.htm`

Expected Output: `https://www.example.com/my-post-slug-for-this-post-2022`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please can you choose between either Excel or Google-Sheets. They are **not** the same application and do have their own functions to solve this issue.

Comment: @JvdV It is a Google Sheet. I updated the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(?:\/?\b\d{4}\/\d\d\/\d\d\b|\.html$)","")
```

I negated the format of `2020/11/05/` since I'm not sure you'd run into any issues using the above suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A,"(?:\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}|\.html?$)", ))
```

[image]